# Getting/Returning A Specific Attribute from a Collection using ComboBox in c#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0

How do I get the attribute "longName" returned when I click on a value from the combo box?

When I run the Code I get:
[image]

But If I click on Anything in the combo box I get the collection returned
[image]

I am guessing I need more trigger events but I am unsure what ones I need. I looked at a few of the suggested answers and they all seemed to be coded rather than XAML trigger events but I was unable to get them to work (as I am still new to c#).

```xml
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4" MinHeight="25" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding longName}" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1E1E1E" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Pink" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    <ComboBox Height="50" Margin="0,20,40,200" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=lineItems}" 
     IsEditable="True" StaysOpenOnEdit="True" Text="{Binding lineItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

```cs
        public class LineItems
        {
            public string variableName { get; set; }
            public string variableUnit { get; set; }
            public bool variableGrowthCheck { get; set; }
            public bool variableAVGCheck { get; set; }
            public bool variableSVCheck { get; set; }
            public string longName { get; set; }
            public int priority { get; set; }
            
        }
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense, you bound `ItemsSource`, `SelectedItem` and `Text` to the same property? What are you expecting to happen with this?

Comment: I copied that part of code from stack overflow can you explain how I should fix it or can you stop just replying if you arent going to help

Comment: When I remove selected item and text what should I bind them to or change them to?

Comment: Bind `ItemsSource` with a *list* of LineItems, and bind `SelectedItem` with a property of type LineItems

Comment: I don't quite understand what you need. Perhaps you should remove the Style for the Item. And in the ComboBox set the value `DisplayMemberPath="longName"`.
If this is not enough, then you will describe in more detail what is in the `lineItems` collection, using an example of filling it.
And how do you want the ComboBox to look when expanded and after the item is selected.

Comment: Hi EldHasp, just Adding DisplayMemberPath="longName" Sorted the problem out. Thank you,